# How to Not display empty rows?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

My question is:

If you look at where it would display "

```
<td>1ST<?php echo $first ?></td>
```

"

How do I ensure that if the row associate to variable '$first' or all the others if they are empty nothing shows. Also that the '1st' doesn't show?

Have tried various things I am stumped on this!

```html
<h2><a href="#"><?php echo $show_title ?></a></h2>
<h4>Show Date: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"> </span><?php echo $show_date ?></h4>
<hr>
</a>
<hr>
<?php

// SO UPDATE THE QUERY TO ONLY PULL THAT SHOW'S DOGS
$query = "SELECT * FROM result
WHERE first IS NOT NULL";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error
("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error
($connection), E_USER_ERROR);

if ($result) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$dog_name = $row['dog_name'];
$placement = $row['placement'];
$class_name = $row['class_name'];
$entries = $row['entries'];
$absentee = $row['absentee'];
$entries = $row['entries'];
$first  = $row['first'];
$second = $row['second'];
$third = $row['third'];
$RES = $row['RES'];
$VHC = $row['VHC'];
$DCC = $row['DCC'];
$RDCC = $row['RDCC'];
$BCC = $row['BCC'];
$RBCC = $row['RBCC'];
$BOB = $row['BOB'];
$BP = $row['BP'];
$BJ = $row['BJ'];

?>

<table class="table" border="0"></div>
<tr>
  <td><strong><?php echo $class_name ?></strong> - <h6>Entries: <?php echo $entries ?> Absentees: <?php echo $absentee ?></h6></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>DCC</td>
  <td><?php echo $DCC ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>RDCC</td>
  <td><?php echo $RDCC ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>BCC</td>
  <td><?php echo $BCC ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>RBCC</td>
  <td><?php echo $RBCC ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>BOB</td>
  <td><?php echo $BOB ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>BP</td>
  <td><?php echo $BP ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>BJ</td>
  <td><?php echo $BJ ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>1ST</td>
  <td><?php echo $first ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2ND</td>
  <td><?php echo $second ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3RD</td>
  <td><?php echo $third ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>RES</td>
  <td><?php echo $RES ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>VHC</td>
  <td><?php echo $VHC ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: (pseudo'ish): `if(row is empty){...}` or a ternary operator.

Comment: Nothing will show when they are empty. Or do you want to remove the whole html table row? Then you'd need to add conditions around  each one. And why are you copying your array to different variables? You can use the array below as well.

Comment: @jeroen Maybe they'll respond to the answer given; *gotta run*.

Comment: Can't you be a bit more clear? you don't want to show the row if ALL its values are empty or if only one is empty whatsoever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing well, just apply a filtering function to each row you recieve:

```
// SO UPDATE THE QUERY TO ONLY PULL THAT SHOW'S DOGS
$query = "SELECT * FROM result
WHERE first IS NOT NULL";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if (!$result) {

    trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);

} else {

    // Fetch results into array
    $data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    // If results array is not empty
    if ($data) {


        echo '<table class="table" border="0"></div>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <strong><?php echo $class_name ?></strong> - <h6>Entries: <?php echo $entries ?> Absentees: <?php echo $absentee ?></h6>
          </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>';

        // Now let's walk through every record
        array_walk($data, function($dogRecord) {

            // Here we apply array_filter to each dog record, so that empty values (i.e. those evaluating to false) are filtered out
            $dogRecord = array_filter($dogRecord);


            // Now loop throw $dogRecord to build table

            $collation = [
                'DCC' => 'DCC',
                'RDCC' => 'RDCC',
                'BCC' => 'BCC',
                'RBCC' => 'RBCC',
                'BOB' => 'BOB',
                'BP' => 'BOB',
                'BJ' => 'BOB',
                '1ST' => 'first',
                '2ND' => 'second',
                '3RD' => 'third',
                'RES' => 'RES',
                'VHC' => 'RES'
            ];

            foreach ($dogRecord as $property => $value) {

                echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$collation[$property].'</td>
                    <td>'.$value.'</td>
                </tr>';

            }

        });


        echo '</table>';
    }

}
```

Note that instead of simple `foreach` loop I'm using `array_walk` function. This is because since you extract variables for each record, you want undeclared (i.e. unoccupied) varables every time.

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        // Show the table-row
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is about; read it over again.

Comment: Basically if the row is empty then it doesn't show 1st, or 2nd etc

Answer (score -2):

The following code will iterate through each row in the result (while loop) and each key => value within each row (foreach loop); it will then check if a value is not null or the key is not equal to 'first' (if statement) and echo the results in the table element. I'm not sure I fully understood your question but I hope this helps in some small way.

```
<table>
<?php
if($result){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    foreach($row as $key => $value){
        if($value != null && $key != 'first'){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $key . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)